# codeception jenkins GuzzleHttp cURL error 52: Empty reply from server

Tags: php, apache, out-of-memory, codeception

When I run tests by jenkins, errors occur with tests of api **ApiTester**.

> [GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException] cURL error 52: Empty reply from server (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl errors.html)

Unit tests run normally.
Locally all tests work.
Only on jenkins server **ApiTester** fails.

**Versions (The same in local and Jenkins server)**:
PHP: 7.0.16-1~dotdeb+8.1
Apache: Apache/2.4.10
Xdebug: 2.5.1

**Curl Test** (curl http://dev.ci.api.flope.com/api/test -v):

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
* Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to dev.ci.api.flope.com (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET /api/test HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
> Host: dev.ci.api.flope.com
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Sat, 18 Mar 2017 02:46:14 GMT
* Server Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
< Status: 200 OK
< Content-Length: 33
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< 
* Connection #0 to host dev.ci.api.flope.com left intact
<html><body>Hello 3</body></html>
```

**api.suite.yml**:

```
class_name: ApiTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - \Helper\Api
        - REST:
            url: http://dev.ci.api.flope.com/api/
            depends: PhpBrowser
            part: Json
        - Asserts
        - Db
```

Update from comments:

> In apache log: Out of memory I was seeing the virtual host log
>   but memory total: 3962, used: 2203 and free: 1758

Comment: Is Jenkins on a different computer or the same computer?

Comment: Empty response often is a sign of segmentation fault. Please check error log of apache. If you run your tests with remote code coverage enabled, try disabling it and see if it helps (if it does, it is a bug of xdebug).

Comment: If you see segmentation fault in error log, please try to find a core dump file and analyze it with gdb: https://bugs.php.net/bugs-generating-backtrace.php

Comment: Augwa: In same computer. Naktibald: remote code coverage is disabled. I will try to find core dump. Thank you all.

Comment: In apache log: Out of memory

I was seeing the virtual host log ...

Comment: but memory total: 3962, used: 2203 and fre: 1758

Comment: How much is that in megabytes? If apache process gets killed everytime you make a request, you have to do some serious optimization or configuration tuning or just give it more memory.

Comment: Today I reinstalled apache2 php7 and modules.
It worked.
I think I must have done something wrong in the settings.
Unfortunately I will not know what.
But problem solved..objective reached.
Thank you all!